# Extract data which is a substring in a file using Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on spark case study where I have csv file in hdfs and I am processing data on spark. Data in one of the column is merged.

For example title column has data:

"EMS: BACK PAINS/INJURY". EMS represent Emergency and after : represent, type of emergency. While loading csv to DF, I have requirement to load only data before (:) (in this case EMS). Here is my code snippet but it load complete title column. Can you help me on how to substring it?

Code:

```
    val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("latitude", DoubleType, true), StructField("longitude",  DoubleType, true), StructField("desc", StringType, true), StructField("zip", StringType, true), StructField("title", StringType, true), StructField("timeStamp", StringType, true), StructField ("twp", StringType, true),StructField("addr", StringType, true), StructField("e", IntegerType, true))) 

val df = spark.read.option("header","true").schema(schema).csv("hdfs://filepath/filename.csv")
```

#

Sample Data:

```
lat|lng|desc|zip|title|timeStamp|twp|addr|e

40.2978759|-75.5812935|REINDEER CT & DEAD END;  NEW HANOVER; Station 332; 2015-12-10 @ 17:10:52;|19525|EMS: BACK PAINS/INJURY|12/10/2015 17:40|NEW HANOVER|REINDEER CT & DEAD END|1

40.2580614|-75.2646799|BRIAR PATH & WHITEMARSH LN;  HATFIELD TOWNSHIP; Station 345; 2015-12-10 @ 17:29:21;|19446|EMS: DIABETIC EMERGENCY|12/10/2015 17:40|HATFIELD TOWNSHIP|BRIAR PATH & WHITEMARSH LN|1

40.1211818|-75.3519752|HAWS AVE; NORRISTOWN; 2015-12-10 @ 14:39:21-Station:STA27;|19401|Fire: GAS-ODOR/LEAK|12/10/2015 17:40|NORRISTOWN|HAWS AVE|1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your `csv` as with `delimiter` as `|`

```
val data = spark.read
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("header", true)
  .schema(schema)
  .csv(path)
  //split the column title and get only befor : part
  .withColumn("title", split($"title", ":")(0))


data.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+-----+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---+
|latitude  |longitude  |desc                                                                               |zip  |title|timeStamp       |twp              |addr                      |e  |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+-----+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---+
|40.2978759|-75.5812935|REINDEER CT & DEAD END;  NEW HANOVER; Station 332; 2015-12-10 @ 17:10:52;          |19525|EMS  |12/10/2015 17:40|NEW HANOVER      |REINDEER CT & DEAD END    |1  |
|40.2580614|-75.2646799|BRIAR PATH & WHITEMARSH LN;  HATFIELD TOWNSHIP; Station 345; 2015-12-10 @ 17:29:21;|19446|EMS  |12/10/2015 17:40|HATFIELD TOWNSHIP|BRIAR PATH & WHITEMARSH LN|1  |
|40.1211818|-75.3519752|HAWS AVE; NORRISTOWN; 2015-12-10 @ 14:39:21-Station:STA27;                         |19401|Fire |12/10/2015 17:40|NORRISTOWN       |HAWS AVE                  |1  |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+-----+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---+
```

Hope this helps!